# Evernote or evernote widget and Thumbnails

Tags: android, evernote

do you know a method or the method used by the evernote widget to retrieve the thumbnails that we see in a very convenient way (before retrieving the entire note) in the main interface or in the widget?
I saw the post method via http request, but it seems complicated when not sharing notes and perhaps there are more straightforward methods via a direct evernote API call or via reading files stored by the application(s)?

Answer (score 0):

The widget pulls the thumbnails from the Evernote app's Content Provider.

Something like this should work.

In your manifest :

```
<permission android:name="evernote.permission.READ_DATA" android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

In your java code:

```
final Uri AUTHORITY_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.evernote.evernoteprovider");
final Uri NOTE_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(AUTHORITY_URI, "notes");

private FileDescriptor getNoteThumbnail(Context context, String noteGuid) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Uri thumbnailUri = NOTE_URI.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath(noteGuid).appendPath("thumbnail").appendPath("data").build();
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    return cr.openFileDescriptor(thumbnailUri, "r").getFileDescriptor();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Post method is not too complex.  I'm not familiar with Java but this is an example in python that should be pretty straightforward to port to android:

```
import requests

ACCESS_TOKEN="INSERT YOUR AUTH TOKEN OR DEV TOKEN HERE"

payload={'auth':ACCESS_TOKEN} #map auth token to param "auth"
r=requests.post('https://sandbox.evernote.com//shard/s1/thm/note/e679c010-d8b2-4644-9eag-56bd31c84be7.jpg?size=75',data=payload, stream=True)  #returns a binary of the picture type in header

f=open('thumbnail.jpg','wb') #open file for binary writing
f.write(r.content) #write binary contents of request to a file
f.close()  #close the file
```

The only parameter of the POST request is "auth" and it should contain your auth token (or dev token).  The rest of the information comes from the URL itself and is of the form:

```
[domain].evernote.com/shard/[shard]/thm/note/[guid]
```

where

[domain] is sandbox (for the sandbox) and www (for production)

[shard] is the shard the account is on (should be something like s1)

[guid] is the notebook guid

with the optional parameters appended at the end of .jpg, .gif, .bmp or .png as well as the optional parameter at the end of the URL ?size=[1 to 299] (default is 300px square)

for example on the sandbox with shard s1, note guid "e669c090-d8b2-4324-9eae-56bd31c64af7" to return a jpg of size 150px square the URL would look like this:

```
https://sandbox.evernote.com/shard/s1/thm/note/e669c090-d8b2-4324-9eae-56bd31c64af7.jpg?size=75
```